# When does the "/mnt/username_home_dir" appear?

Tags: mount, users

The problem I have to solve requires the access to the `/mnt/username_home_dir` directory, but there is no such directory present, despite me creating a user and auto-creation of his `/home/username` directory.

(I'm assuming that the directory is supposed be auto-created so it can be connected to the account to serve its function, and that simply creating an appropriately-named folder in `/mnt` won't do anything?)

Comment: I've never seen /mnt/username_home_dir, what system are you using?

Comment: May be you have mulled it with `/media/user_name` dir?

Comment: I'm using Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-21-5

Comment: @Costas and the problem was written by an university teacher, so I am wary assuming the mistake/typo on his part. (Perhaps when my classmates won't be able to find the directory either.)

Comment: If it was written by your teacher, I suspect it refers to a particular configuration that was presented in class - perhaps mounting of remote home directories using `autofs`